# Blacklisting a package (grub-pc) and leave recommendations unresolved

Tags: apt, grub2, dependencies, pxe

I use PXE-boot on a system, and hence do not require any local bootloaders like grub. When uninstalling `grub-pc` it complains that the kernel image recommends it, something like

`linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic recommends grub-pc | grub-efi-amd64 | grub-efi-ia32| grub | lilo`

Which I can ignore. If a new version of the kernel comes along it will install `grub-pc` again based on the (renewed) recommendation.

`grub-pc` usually fails post install, or causes some other problems, which I would like to avoid.

How do get rid of grub for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are booting using PXE, do you even need the kernel installed locally?  You might be able to simply remove the kernel packages.

For ignoring the apt dependency, there are a couple of options.  Although none are particularly great.  I'd probably create and install a dummy `grub-pc` package using `equivs`.

https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/HackingDependencies

Here is another question where more options are discussed for manipulating dependencies - https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies

Comment: This actually looks like the best option I see. Theoretically I could remove the kernel, but copy the kernel image the initrd over for pxe boot. This way I always have the most recent Ubuntu kernel, have the right configuration for the initrd, and have less requierements on the remote machine